User profile size too large
I have a computer which complains about "Profile being to big" for a  user.
The profile folder (C:\Users\username) is  2.5 GB.
What could be the reason?
How can I get rid of the message which reappears several seconds after closing it?

Is that user configured to use a roaming user profile? In that case, the profile needs to be synced to the network share that is used as the main storage for roaming profiles on every logout, and loaded from there on login unless the local copy is already in sync. If the profile becomes too big, this can generate a lot of network traffic on login/logout and make logins and logouts slow.
Leaving large files on desktop or storing custom subfolders within the profile folder (outside the folders subject to folder redirection, like Documents and Pictures for example) would cause the profile to grow in size.
Also, if the user roams between two or more versions of Windows, there might be separate copies of the profile for each version, which would multiply the total size of the user's profile(s) on the profile storage share.
Back in Windows NT4 era, I used to maintain a Windows domain with roaming profiles. We had some specialized software that was not exactly designed according to Microsoft's recommended practices of that time, and on default settings, it used to store some caches or other non-essential data in the roaming profile, causing the profile to bloat. We had to customize the configuration of that software a bit to avoid that.
You might want to check the contents of the "master" copy of the roaming profile on the network share (see the Profile path entry in the properties of the Active Directory user), and see if the profile contains abnormally large files or directories.
Then work with the user to see if those files can be stored elsewhere or removed altoghether.

The policy is Limit profile size
Using Group Policy Management Console or Group Policy Editor, it is located at:
User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > User Profiles.
The registry values are located at:
Key: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
Value: EnableProfileQuota
Value Type: REG_DWORD
Value: MaxProfileSize
Value Type: REG_DWORD
This policy setting sets the maximum size of each user profile and determines the system response when a user profile reaches the maximum size. This policy setting affects both local and roaming profiles.
If you disable this policy setting or do not configure it, the system does not limit the size of user profiles.
If you enable this policy setting, you can:

Set a maximum permitted user profile size.
Determine whether the registry files are included in the calculation of the profile size.
Determine whether users are notified when the profile exceeds the permitted maximum size.
Specify a customized message notifying users of the oversized profile.
Determine how often the customized message is displayed.


